# Threading Wait During While Loop

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

My application has 1 global driver, which is responsible for doing the low-level work.
I then have 2 threads, both of which use infinite loops to get some work done. My question is how to allow 1 thread to use the driver as much as possible, but giving a chance to the second thread to use it when necessary.

To elaborate, the code I have is as follows:

```
public class Game {
    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Game.class);

    private WebDriverController controller;

    public Game(WebDriverController controler) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public void startThreadA() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    synchronized (LOCK) {
                        controller.doSomethingA();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void startThreadB() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    ...
                    ...
                    synchronized (LOCK) {
                        controller.doSomethingB();
                    }
                    ...
                    ...
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

The logic is to allow the first thread to execute `doSomethingA()` as much as possible, with the second thread only acquiring the lock to complete little tasks and then giving the lock back to the first thread.

Using this code, the first thread will continuously use the controller to do what it needs to do, whereas the second thread gets stuck waiting at its synchronized block. The way I have currently fixed this is by adding a pause to the first thread, to give the second thread a chance to acquire the lock, as follows:

```
public void startThreadA() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                synchronized (LOCK) {
                    controller.doSomethingA();
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    LOGGER.error(null, e);
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

This does work exactly as intended, but it doesn't seem right. I'm not happy with the manual pause after each iteration, especially if the second thread does not need the lock as it's wasting time.

What do I replace the pause with to make this more efficient?

Comment: If the second thread only does small tasks, you may as well move the work into the first thread.  This will make you code a lot simpler and possibly more efficient.

Comment: @PeterLawrey The tasks are small, but there are many of them. The idea is to allow the first thread to execute whenever the second thread does not need the driver for its' tasks.

Comment: Given only one thread can ever hold the lock, you effectively only have one running thread at any time.  You only gain complexity unless the threads can execute concurrently/independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are approaching this from the wrong direction, as in your current setup 99.999% of the time thread A calls for a monitor the processing time is wasted. However as I do not have enough details about your actual problem, here is a quick solution using a ReentrantLock with fair scheduling (FIFO):

```
protected final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true); // fair scheduling

public void functionA() {
  lock.lock();
  try {
    controller.functionA();
  } finally {
    lock.unlock();
  }
}

public void functionB() {
  lock.lock();
  try {
    controller.functionB();
  } finally {
    lock.unlock();
  }
}
```

**Explanation:**

If Thread A is currently holding the lock and Thread B calls, B is guaranteed to receive the monitor right after A releases it, even if A immediately (before any thread switch occurs) calls for it again.

Comment: "Thread B is guaranteed to receive the monitor right affter ... "  is just plain wrong. This code is practically functionally equivalent to the OP's original version, without the sleep, and will likely starve the second thread of the resources, exactly the same way.

Comment: No it is not. The fair scheduling guarantees that calls are processed in order and not semi-randomly as with synchronized.

Comment: The problem is not with the order of lock acquisition but with assuring that a context switch occurs. You need to hint the scheduler, that your thread doesn't mind waiting for a bit.

Comment: From the docs: `Note however, that fairness of locks does not guarantee fairness of thread scheduling. Thus, one of many threads using a fair lock may obtain it multiple times in succession while other active threads are not progressing and not currently holding the lock.`

Comment: I'm not too particular in the details of 'how', but this solution works perfectly for me. Replacing the synchronized blocks with lock acquisitions is allowing the two threads to proceed, without having to introduce a delay. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why you use `synchronized` in `run()`? Use `synchronized` or `Lock` in your methods in `WebDriverController`.

```
public void doSomeThingA(){
   lock.lock();
   try {
      //your stuff
   } finally {
       lock.unlock();
   }
}
```

And in run method of Thread invoke these methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would the `WebDriverController` lock be a class variable, used by the class' methods?

Comment: Yes. In your WebDriverController you can use one of Lock implementation

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll move the lock functionality out of the run method and into the controller.

Comment: Take a look at [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) and [Lock Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html)

Answer (score -1):

There are a few options here. The best bet in this instance is likely to be remove the responsibility of deciding when to do work from the threads and instead, waiting for an event from a monitor to release the threads to do work. You can then schedule the work in whichever ratio is best suited to the purpose.

Alternatively, remove the lack of thread safety from your controller code.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that above thread organization is the best way to go for your particular case, your problem is that first thread holds the lock too long, thus starving the second one.

You can check if doSomethingA function really needs locked driver all the time while it is being executed (in most cases it doesn't), and if not split it into multiple smaller execution blocks, some of which hold the lock while other's don't. This will create more time for second thread to kick in when it needs to.

If that cannot be done then you really need to rethink your app, because you have created a resource bottleneck.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like `Thread.yield ()` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Let me quote from the docs why this is a bad idea: "The scheduler is free to ignore this hint." and "It is rarely appropriate to use this method. It may be useful for debugging or testing purposes"

Comment: Don't know how you interpret that excerpt as "this is a bad idea" ... Perhaps, you have a better handle at the English language than I do ...

Comment: Coding a "solution" that according to the docs "might or might not work" results in code that might or might not work. And if it works on your machine, it is not guaranteed to work on the target machine, so you might just sit there during release spending all night to hunt down the issue. Therefore this is a bad idea.

Comment: The docs do not say it "might or might not work".  It just says that thread scheduling is non-deterministic. This is true for any solution, so, effectively, carries no specific applicability to the problem at hand.